# Show an increasing function with an interval as a range is continuous

Tags: functions

My professor gave us this problem out of his book:
Show, if f: [a, b] --> R is an increasing function and the range of f is an interval, then f is continuous

I'm not sure if I'm understanding correctly though. Wouldn't "the range of f is an interval" just mean that there is some A=[f(a),f(b)]? Why would that mean that f is continuous? Couldn't there be a hole in that range?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The range is an interval so it couldn't possibly have a hole since then it wouldn't be an interval.

Comment: By range, your prof means image, i.e. $f$ is meant to be surjective on an interval.

Answer (score 3):

For this problem, the range has to be understood to include only those values that the function maps to.  So, for example, if $f(x)=\begin {cases} x& 0 \le x \le 1 \\x+1& 1 \lt x \le 2 \end {cases}$ the range would be $[0,1] \cup (2,3]$, not $[0,3]$.  Otherwise, you are correct, there could be a hole.

Comment: Thank you! So how would that definition of the range help prove that the function is continuous if the range only has the values that f maps to? It doesn't seem like you can use that to show that f is in fact continuous

Answer (score 2):

To prove that $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ it suffices to show that the preimage of any closed set in $[f(a),f(b)]$ is closed.  It suffices to prove this for closed intervals, since any closed set in $[f(a),f(b)]$ is the union of subintervals and points.

So let $I$ be a subinterval in $[f(a),f(b)]$. Then by surjectivity $I=[f(s),f(t)]$ for some $s$ and $t$ in $[a,b]$.  We claim that the preimage of $[f(s),f(t)]$ is $[s,t]$.  To see this let $c\in [f(a),f(b)]$.  Then $c=f(r)$ for some $r\in [a,b]$ (again by surjectivity).  We now must show that $r\in [s,t]$.  But this follows since $f$ is increasing. I.e, if $r<s$ or $r>t$ then we get the respective contradictions $f(r)<f(s)$ and $f(r)>f(t)$. We're done since $[s,t]$ is obviously closed.